# Image scaling in javascript and HTML5 algorithm for pixeldata results in coarse images?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, html5-canvas

I’m trying to use the Cornerstone DICOM parser (https://github.com/cornerstonejs/dicomParser) to extract the pixeldata for a CT scan using javascript and HTML5 canvas. 
I need to be able to reduce the size of the reulting pixeldata.
Is used the hermite-resize algorithm:
https://github.com/viliusle/Hermite-resize

Please see my following proof of concept which show an axial slice of the upper abdomen:
http://castlemountain.dk/dicomParser/index2.html

As you can see two types of compressed images are generated (image 2 and image 3) where it is apparent that image 2 is more coarse than image 3 (especially when looking at the ribs). I use the same compression algorithm but when getting the pixeldata from drawing the uncompressed pixeldata (image 1) then the image quality is better for image 3 and I can’t seem to figure out why that is. HTML5 canvas related?

The example is as follows:

Firstly, I extract the CT pixeldata for the 512x512 px CT image which is subsequently converted to 0-255 greyscale values with CT window/level (method convertToGreylevel).
This array of greyscale pixel values is then used to generate an imageData object (imgData) for HMLT5 canvas and this is shown as an uncompressed image (Image 1):

```
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

Next the function

```
pixelData2 = resample_hermite(pixelData[slices], 512, 512, 
Math.round(512/compression2), Math.round(512/compression2));
```

Is used to generate compressed pixeldata (256x256 px) which are used to generate an imageData object which is shown (Image 2):

```
ctx.putImageData(imgData2,512,0);
```

Afterwards the

```
var imgInput = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 512, 512);
```

Is used to get the imageData from the first 512x512 image drawn to canvas.
The pixeldata from canvas is extracted and used to generate an array of pixeldata which is compressed with the:

```
var outputData = resample_hermite(inputData, 512, 512,Math.round(512/compression2), Math.round(512/compression2));
```

This resulting array of pixeldata (256x256 pixel) is used to generate HMTL5 image object which is shown (Image 3):

```
ctx.putImageData(img2, 512, Math.round(512/compression2));
```

Image 2 is definitely more coarse (see the white ribs) than compressed image 3.
Can anyone point me in the direction why that is?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using old Hermite-resize lib version, you have operations with "0.5", but original lib does not have anything similar.

After fixing resample_hermite function (basically removing 0.5, but i recommend using latest code from github), results are much better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you mean by 'operation with "0.5"', but I have replaced the 0.5 in the hermite function with 0.0 and the new version is here:
http://castlemountain.dk/dicomParser/index3.html
But removing the 0.5 seems to make both image 3 and 2 coarse!?!!?

Again regarding:
http://castlemountain.dk/dicomParser/index2.html
Could you weight in on why putting the dicom pixeldata to canvas and using getimagedata to subsequently running the hermite function provides better image quality (image 3) than just running the pixeldata directly through the Hermite function?

Comment: @user3220072 "make both image 3 and 2 coarse!?" - this hermite resize function works better, if resize ratio is greater then 2, yours is 2. If you only want to change oriignal size no more then 100%, you can use simple drawImage() - it works really nice (it will only give you ugly results if resize ratio is above 100%, for example 512 -> 200 )

Comment: OK, I seem to have located the error. I forgot to do parseInt on the windowCenter and windowWdith of the DICOM data. Not that I have done that both the image 2 and image 3 appears smooth with a compression factor of 2.
Please see:
http://castlemountain.dk/dicomParser/index4.html

Comment: However, now I try to wait to apply windowCenter and windowWidth on the pixelData until after I have applied the Hermite scaling filter, please see:
http://castlemountain.dk/dicomParser/index5.html
This means that the hermite filter recieves input of pixeldata in the range of Hounsfield units (i.e. approx 0-4096). 
After this filtering the convertToGreylevel method is applied to the pixeldata output from Hermite filtering.
This results in a coarse image again (image 2).
Does the hermite filter work pixelValues in the range of 0-4096?

Sincerely